# Why is Angular ActivatedRoute.routeConfig not always valid?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Depending on a variety of situations, `routeConfig` may be null, or it may be valid.  I'm trying to figure out why or when it's valid and when it's not.  I want to use it for dynamic loading, but I can't rely on it, because it's not always valid. So far,

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('route config', this.activatedRoute.routeConfig);
  }
}
```

My route module (per request)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
]
const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
};
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config),
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
  ]
})
export class RoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: What did you encounter that indicated it wasn't valid?

Comment: The routeConfig was null